# Use newcommand in newenvironment

Tags: macros, environments

I want create an environment with `newenvironment` that does the following: it evaluates the height of the environment and then prints it as many times (textheight/height) as will fit upon one page.

Here is an attempt to print the environment twice:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newenvironment{double}{\newcommand{\todouble}\bgroup}{\egroup\todouble\todouble}
\begin{document}
\begin{double}
    Hello, World!
\end{double}
\end{document}
```

My first idea is to use `\newenvironment` to define an environment that uses `\newcommand` to define a command `\todouble`  that contains the contents of the environment. At the end of the environment `\todouble` is called twice.

But this fails with the error:

```
! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
\enddouble ->\egroup 
                 \todouble \todouble 
l.6 \end{double}
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? If you just want to save the contents of an env in a macro, see the `environ` package.

Comment: Oh, `environ` seems very good - I'll use it for another task :) Thanks for information!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't use `\bgroup` for delimiting a mandatory argument. And you want leaders to fill up the page with copies of what you absorbed.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newenvironment{double}
 {%
  \par % be in vertical mode
  \setbox0=\vbox\bgroup % start a box
  \strut % ensure good height for the first line
  \ignorespaces % ignore the end of line
 }
 {%
  \egroup % end the box
  \hrule height0pt % vertical analog of \leavevmode
  \cleaders\copy0\vfill % repeat as much as necessary
 }
\begin{document}
\begin{double}
    Hello, World!
\end{double}
\end{document}
```

[image]

An extended version that checks whether at least two copies of the box fit in the page and just prints the box if not.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newenvironment{double}
 {%
  \par % be in vertical mode
  \setbox0=\vbox\bgroup % start a box
  \strut % ensure good height for the first line
  \ignorespaces % ignore the end of line
 }
 {%
  \ifhmode\strut\fi\egroup % end the box
  % see if at least two copies of the box fit in the page
  \ifdim\ht0 < \dimexpr .5\textwidth-4ex\relax
    \hrule height0pt % vertical analog of \leavevmode
    \cleaders\copy0\vfill % repeat as much as necessary
    \clearpage
  \else
    \unvbox0
    \clearpage
  \fi
 }
\begin{document}
\begin{double}
    Hello, World!
\end{double}

\begin{double}
\lipsum*[2]
\end{double}

\begin{double}
\lipsum
\end{double}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! I think I should learn a bit more about LaTeX...

Comment: @uzsolt `\leaders` are not in the LaTeX manual. Consult TeX by Topic (or the TeXbook) for them.

Comment: your solution doesn't work when the text's height is more than a page height. How can I fix it?

Comment: @uzsolt How can you fill a page with something that's bigger than the page? Do you want to truncate it?

Comment: Good question :) Is it possible to modify your solution to handle this situation? If the body is bigger than a page should be two (or more) page.

Comment: @uzsolt Doesn't make much sense. Say the box is one and a half page; what should go and where?

Comment: The first page into the first page, second page into second page :) Cleanly: if smaller than a page, multiply; if bigger than a page, stay original.

Comment: @uzsolt Not well defined, anyway. With leaders, only full copies of the object can be used. If the object is 3/4 of a page, what do you expect?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot this case. In this case stay original. 

The reason why I want this: I'm a teacher and I used to create exercises for students. And if the exercise is small, I want multiply (so I can print many into one page and shouldn't give a small exercise and a big white empty part on one page).

Comment: @uzsolt Added new version

Comment: Great! I want add a plus upvote :) Thank you very much!